# Why do I get for every call to the Facebook open graph the same action-instance-id?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am currently trying out the Facebook Open Graph.

When I successfully post an action to the Open Graph I get as the described in the documentation the action-instance-id.

```
{
  id: “{action-instance-id}”
}
```

But I always get the same response. So the same ID. Even if I try different actions the result stays the same. Is this expected behavior? I would expect every action instance to get a new id. Or is it only for my developer account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure you're posting a new action, and not reading the details of the existing action? Including your code might help

It looks like you're making a GET request to the action ID, not posting a new user->action->object connection, as those will have unique IDs

Comment: Hi @Igy, I use the example code that is provided by Facebook in their developers section. curl -F 'access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
     -F 'movie=http://samples.ogp.me/453907197960619' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/[namespace]:[action]' so I think that is not the problem.

Comment: Having a closer look now I was mistaken. Because the first and last numbers of the id where the same for all and only the numbers in the middle of the id differed. The problem lay in that my DELETE HTTP posts were not working correclty.